# parameter not send in ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I want to call the action method(AddCompare) using an Ajax request at the View,

My problem is that the parameter sent to AddCompare Action always has zero value,
While the parameter value in the function AddToCompare is correct

this is my code

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Products>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <div class="left-block">

            <div class="quick-view">
                <a title="Add To Compare" class="heart" href="#" onclick="AddToCompare(15)"></a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </li>
}

<script>
function AddToCompare(param) {
        alert(param);  //display correct value 15

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("AddCompare")",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    id: param

                }),
            success: function (response) {

                var myObject = eval('(' + response.d + ')');

                if (myObject > 0) {


                    $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Data saved successfully</li></ul>");

                }

                else {

                    $(".errMsg").append("<ul><li>Opppps something went wrong.</li></ul>");

                }

                $(".errMsg").show("slow");


            },

            error: function (response) {

                alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);

            }

        });

    }
</script>
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult AddCompare(int id)
{
   //id is zero !!!
    int param=id;
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you try using type: "POST" in your Ajax request? I think that in a GET request, the parameters should be in the URI.

Comment: yes, i use POST in Ajax request but not solve

Comment: try $.get,  this is the syntax $.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)

Comment: @Bosco . Yesssss ,tank you. please post this answer to i accept

Comment: Can you try setting processData: false in your Ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
$.get
```

this is the syntax

```
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call you don't need to stringify

```
 $.ajax({
    // your code
    data: {id: param},
```

Decorate your action method with `HttpGet` even if it is `GET` by default. Just a better practice.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult AddCompare(int id)
{

}
```

Comment: no error or exception, only id value in Action is zero

Comment: I used the above code to locally test on my machine, it does work.  Check your network tabs if it is passing that value also check your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Get verb you can do this:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Controller/Action?ID=" + id,
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function (response) {
                    //response code here 
                });
```

Change the controller and the action to your needs and you can add other settings to the ajax if needed.